# Typescript recurrent type intersection

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I tried to define a **type definition for recurrent intersection**, to achieve such kind of behaviour:

```js
type merged = Merged<[{a: string}, {b: string}, ...]>
```

to be `{a: string} & {b: string} & ...`

I defined some type utilities like `Head` and `Tail` to be able to operate on a variable number of input types and managed to define recurrent union, but failed to achieve the same for intersection :(

```js
type Head<T extends any[]> = T[0]
type Tail<T extends any[]> =
((...args: T) => any) extends ((_arg0: any, ...rest: infer R) => any) ? R : never

type United<T extends any[]> = {
  0: Head<T>
  1: United<Tail<T>>
}[ T extends ([] | [any])
  ? 0
  : 0 | 1
]

type Merged<T extends any[]> = {
  0: Head<T>
  1: Merged<Tail<T>>
}[T extends ([] | [any])
  ? 0
  : 0 & 1
]

type a = {a: string}
type b = {b: string}
type c = {c: string}

type head = Head<[a, b, c, d]>       // {a: string} OK
type tail = Tail<[a, b, c, d]>       // [b, c]      OK
type united = United<[a, b, c, d]>   // a | b | c   OK
type merged = Merged<[a, b, c, d]>   // unknown     Not good
```

I must be failing on some base internals of TypeScript, but have no idea **why it worked in case of union and did not in case of intersection**?

How can I fix it maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't try to do anything recursive here, especially because that sort of recursive indexing is [not supported](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980#issuecomment-421354117).

Also, intersections of key types are almost always going to collapse to something `never`-like, so will get `never` or `unknown` or something undesirable out of it.  That is, indexed access doesn’t necessarily distribute across intersections:

```
type OOPS = { a: a, b: b }["a" & "b"] // never! not a & b
```

Instead, I'd use the solution offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type) to take a union and convert it to an intersection:

```
type Merged<A extends readonly any[]> =
    A[number] extends infer U ?
    (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ?
    I : never : never;


type a = { a: string }
type b = { b: string }
type c = { c: string }
type d = { d: string }
type merged = Merged<[a, b, c, d]>   // a & b & c & d
```

That should work for you.  Hope it helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=4&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=1#code/FAguE8AcFMAIFloCcDm0AmAeAgraAPUaAO3QGdYloBDdAe2IBtxZrjwBtAXQD5YBeYLGGxsHYgFcAtgCNkXPIRLlYAS2IAzZLACqsAPxCRACj0EipCmxb7YxgNYAuXQEoBfAG51V6WM+LQHshu5soUxg7O6lpIsACSbvye3uhuhiLxfrABQbH+gcgA3GBQcNQCsADerM5koEjqKLAAvsAQMLAyFdUytfWNLW2lsADG3aN9DcRNre1wvvxVsOiTA7PDUshoCwhbGJgc1AA0nScjJ+i8IgD016ywAGSdj6Mv6CBDHQDyXwAKAMrjajOY6dZxdZocABE1ChLyhMihXBAQA)